# Android project shows the `android` module not found

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run a download Android Project, there shows the `android` module is red.

[image]

why there is the error?  can this embody any wrong configuration?

Comment: File > Invalidate Cache / Restart

Comment: I tried but not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your project and invalidate cache and restart your project . sometime this error occur when Resource file R.java which holds the reference is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably Android SDK Location is wrong/moved or not specified.

Open Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK

Make sure Android SDK Location is set correctly.

And atleast one Android SDK Platform is installed. You can install more than one Android Platforms.

[image]